# Codeigniter does not display current session loggerd in user's name

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to display the name of the current user.

In view (dashboard.php)

```
<?php 
$username = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
echo $username;
?>
```

My database have a field "name" in table 'users'. The name of the users are saved here. but the output I get is just "name"

So, I added this following

```
<?php 
$username = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
echo $username;
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
?>
```

the output is

> name Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1583656504 [name] => name [] =>
>   [logged_in] => 1 )

Where and what is the issue?

I registered new user, the values are saved properly in database, I can login too. 
but couldn't display the logged in user's name.

Login.php (controller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {


function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

// Load url helper
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library(['form_validation','session']);
        $this->load->database();

        //load the Login Model
        $this->load->model('UserLogin', 'login');
}

    public function index()
    {

        $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        if($logged_in){


            //if yes redirect to welcome page
            redirect(base_url().'app/dashboard');
        }

     $data['title'] = 'Login';
        $this->load->view('app/login', $data);

    }

        public function doLogin() {
        //get the input fields from login form

        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = sha1($this->input->post('password'));

        //send the email pass to query if the user is present or not
        $check_login = $this->login->checkLogin($email, $password);
        //if the result is query result is 1 then valid user
        if ($check_login) {

         // $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);
         $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $check_login);


            redirect(base_url().'app/dashboard');
        } else {
            //if no then set the session 'logged_in' as false
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', false);

            //and redirect to login page with flashdata invalid msg
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Username / Password Invalid');
            redirect(base_url().'app/login');            
        }
    }

        public function logout() {
        //unset the logged_in session and redirect to login page
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        redirect(base_url().'app/login');
    }
}
```

checklogin() code

```
<?php
    class UserLogin extends CI_Model{
         public function checkLogin($email, $password) {

        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->num_rows();

    }
```

Comment: show your register & session setting code  here

Comment: @BoominathanElango please check now

Comment: where are you setting the name in session ?

Comment: i removed and changed to 'logged_in'

Comment: can you show the checkLogin() function code here

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your approach, you are printing username

```
$username = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
echo $username;
```

but you have not assigned username anywhere, so to accomplish this you have some options, in your login class

```
class UserLogin extends CI_Model{
  public function checkLogin($email, $password) {
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
      if($query->num_rows())
      {
        $user = $query->row_array();
        print_r($user); die(); // remove die after testing
        return $user;
      }
  return false;
}
```

than you can echo:

```
$user = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
echo $user['username'];
```

second issue is it is very insecure to login user this way, you can implement md5 or other encryption on password. ie:

```
$this->db->where('password', md5( $password));
```

or better user [ion_auth library](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/), which by default provide you various options.

Comment: Its empty and 'name' is not printing. For password. I am using $password = sha1($this->input->post('password')); on controllers

Comment: It is 'name' in my table. i did echo $user['name'] but name not visible. then i  print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); but i can see my name here-> Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1583746813 [name] => shebas [loggedin] => 1 [logged_in] => 1 )

Comment: what is the output of `$user = $this->session->userdata('logged_in'); print_r($user); die();`

Comment: just this number -> 1

Comment: test again with `checkLogin` I updated now, and post here the output

Comment: Array ( [id] => 6 [name] => shebas [company] => [phone] => [email] => myemailr@gmail.com [password] => 7c4a8d09ca376f8941b [level] => [status] => [date_time] => 2020-03-04 16:45:57 )

Comment: great, don't forget to remove above output with your email in it, and mark question solved if its fixed. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change the `CheckLogin()` like following then check the userdata

```
public function checkLogin($email, $password) {
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() == '1'){
        $data = $query->row_array();
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('name'=>$data['name'],'loggedin'=>'1'));         
    }
    return $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now. but I cant( echo $data['name'] )in my view. how can i just display the name on my view

Comment: you can print the name anywhere using this $this->session->userdata('name');

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do changes in  model

```
class UserLogin extends CI_Model
{
     public function checkLogin($email, $password) {

    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    return $this->db->get('users');


}
```